# How to collect logs from Integration Flow steps

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a few different integration flows on my application, currently they run based on a cron, they are instantiated from my MessagingGateway, so I send a header called "executionId" when my flows runs , so I would want to log all the activity that a "run" do.

any ideas on how to catch every log from my flow? for example logs like

`"file x has been successfully transferred"`

`"Cannot delete local file x. The local file may be busy in some other process."`

I would need the same logs output that are already on the messageProcessors / handlers, is there any way to catch them all and write it to database based on my executionId which is on the message Header?

currently I'm adding .log everywhere and onSuccessChannel on advice, but I think there should be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a global purpose you can use a `WireTap` bean with a `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` and particular channel names/patterns configuration. Essentially that `log()` does exactly the same `wireTap`, but in particular place. With a `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` you'll add such a `WireTap` into all those channels which bean names matches a configuration.

See more info in the Reference Manual:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/core.html#channel-interceptors

Comment: thank you, got it up and running, now if I would need to get the messages post activities? I mean, "ftp has uploaded the files", for now I just get all messages together, or by the way, how I match for example a .handle() with an Ftp.outbound?

Comment: Yes, that can work too. If existing `WireTap` doesn't fit your requirements, you really can implement your own `ChannelInterceptor` and configure it as a `@Bean` alongside with the `@GlobalChannelInterceptor`. It works on the class level only if your class is a `@Component` as well. But if you configure it as a `@Bean`, the `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` must go there.

Comment: It's working, but I don't know in which "phase" of the flow it is, is there any way to know if it's being processed by an handle / being splitted or something like that ? I have the message + headers now, so if there's no way of doing it so i'll have to do a enrichHeaders telling phase? thanks

Comment: For that purpose we suggest a `Message History` pattern implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history